# Rails production log: "can't dump hash with default proc" for Sass cache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, compilation, sass, assets

I'm displaying every iteration of a record with a text file in it that generates SCSS code (within the markup) based on the file.

This works on my local machine, but not on the server. Checking the log file on the server wields this error:

```
Warning. Error encountered while saving cache 207b5d2f6eb7b9bc6c3519448f6bbfb3e2c9423f/application.sassc: can't dump hash with default proc
```

As it stands, the assets on my project have to be manually precompiled.
So I'm guessing that it's attempting to write these additions in the markup to the manifested `application.scss` but can't because it won't allow for the assets to be compiled.

Should I be compiling these assets? Or precompiling? How should this be handled?

Note again that this works fine on my local machine.

Comment: Have you tried deleting the cache directory on your server?

Comment: I don't understand how that would help. I did, though and the error is still there.

Answer (score 0):

This issue seems to be occuring for us as well if we are using any font url like below:

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,100,100italic,300,300ita‌​lic,400italic,500,500italic,700,700italic,900italic,900);
```

Sort of structure, [here is relevant discussion](https://github.com/rails/sass-rails/issues/331). Solution seems to be not use this for now, unfortunately.

OR

I faced this issue because of [this issue in active_skin gem](https://github.com/SoftwareBrothers/active_skin/issues/35) and the solution in the comment to rename `application.css` to `application.css.scss` seems to fix the problem.